# How to change the value of a global variable inside a sub in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way for me to change the value of a global variable through say an if else statement inside a sub in vb.net

```
Public Class stuff
 Public Shared C As Integer
end class

Public class other stuff
Private Sub C5pts_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles C5pts.CheckedChanged
        If C5pts.Checked Then

        End If
    End Sub
end class
```

I'm trying to change the value of C in this `if then statement` but I'm confused as to how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can :

```
If C5pts.Checked Then
    Stuff.C = 123
End if
```